# 2 lists need to become 1 Most efficient way

Tags: c#, list

I am making an application that will get information from the exchange server and put it in a list. the list i want is made by 2 commands and give me 2 lists aswell. what i am looking for is an efficient way to putting these 2 lists together.

List one has the following objects

- string Name
- string alias
- string email

List two has the folowing ones

- string alias
- decimal itemcount
- double size

What would be the best way of making these 2 lists one? I want to display it in one Dataview.
Also if possible please include Examples/References. im still pretty new to this all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make two lists one," as I can think of any number of things that might mean?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly by, "making these two lists one"? Can you give a concrete example of two lists and the expected output? (Further, what have you tried so far?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want one entry for each user, where the `alias` field is the key to join in. In that case, the easiest is to use LINQ:

```
var newList =  (from a in list1
                join b in list2
                on a.alias equals b.alias
                select new
                {
                  a.Alias,
                  a.Name,
                  a.Email,
                  b.ItemCount,
                  b.Size
                }).ToList();
```

It will solve the problem. Unless you have extremely high volumes of data and responsiveness demands it will be efficient enough.

Comment: This is indeed what i was looking for. Thank you im going to try it right away :)

Comment: Ok, im running into an error. tried a couple of things but cannot figure it out. so please help me if u can.
i get the following 2 errors: "Expected contextual keyword 'equals'"
and "The name 'b' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'"

Comment: never mind, i found the issue. needed to replace the = for 'equals'

Comment: You're right of course. I've never really liked the `equals` keyword and obviously tries to avoid it ;-) Thanks for the edit.